# Importing WPS output (.wpd) tables in R

Tags: r, import

I can't find anything on importing .wpd files (the WPS SAS tables) into R. Does anyone know how to import these tables in R?

I know you can use the foreign and Hmisc libraries to import sas7bdat files but so far I haven't found anything for .wpd.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe through an ODBC connection? Otherwise you might be forced to export a delimited text file and import it in R, since wpd is not a very common file format; there might not be any way to import those files directly into R.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, unfortunately its bad timing (currently in a gap between WPS license expiring and getting renewed), otherwise I would just export as a csv.

Comment: Hi! I am wondering have you found a solution? using R or Python to import wpd files directly. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have come across one solution which whilst not elegant it seems to work from wps to **r studio**.

Output your data set using the `libname`. The file will then be called `mydataset.sas7bdat`.  You can continue to use this dataset in said format in wps.

```
libname out sas7bdat 'path to folder';

data out.mydataset;
set dataset;
run;
```

Then if you use the package `haven`

```
install.packages("haven")
library(haven)
Haven <- read_sas("filepath/dataset.sas7bdat")
```

You will be able to see your dataset and use it.
I'm sure there are a couple of other work arounds, I just find this quickest.

Also `proc r` is pretty good on wps using import nowadays.